# How to Image Trace a white logo or text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, image-trace, white

Using Photoshop CS5, I made a logo in white and transfered it to Illustrator to vectorize. It did not have a background when moving it. Once in Illustrator, it makes the whole rectangle white, making the logo invisible. What do I need to do to image trace my logo?

Comment: Please explain exactly how you 'moved' and 'transported' it, because there are a lot of different factors here that could influence the issue.

Answer (score 5):

**Make it *not* white before using Illustrator.**

Although, depending upon the artwork, there may be better options than using Image Trace in Illustrator. For example.... merely export paths to Illustrator from within Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a work around for this that doesn't involve exporting from Photoshop, which can reduce the resolution, which in turn creates a poor image trace in Illustrator.

1. select the image
2. Edit
3. Edit colours
4. Invert colours

This inverts the white to black which is readable by the image trace function.

Comment: This should have more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change the color of your logo with photoshop, then revert it to white after tracing with illustrator and removing the white background.

Answer (score 0):

I usually save the image as a PNG file with a transparent background instead of JPG. By doing that your artwork will save without adding the unintentional white background.

Now when you open the file in illustrator you should be able to live trace it easily.

Answer (score -1):

On this particular query *"it makes the whole rectangle white, making the logo invisible. What do I need to do to image trace my logo?"*
Try this step, 
1. Export the logo in high resolution from photoshop, then import it in illustrator. 
2. then choose object > imagetrace (or select from top menu )